# PHP HTML FORM sends _POST data but not _FILES

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that sends a file, yet it's not being able to be called after submit.

Form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="#" id="login" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="testy"> 
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The value of `testy` comes up just fine, but nothing from _FILES after it's uploaded.

This was working when I was sending from one page to another page, but since I moved it all to happen on the same page, it's no longer working. What am I missing?

`$_POST['test']` shows `testy`

`$_FILES['file']` shows empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="#" id="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="testy"> 
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something stupid. Will this screw up any forms that don't contain a file upload (it's an optional field).

Comment: no, it should not be a problem for forms without file upload

Comment: Done, at the time it was too soon.

Comment: sorry, i was a bit rash

Comment: Silly StackOverflow and their 15 minute rule! :) thanks again